# How to insert a DNS into /etc/hosts through a bash script?

Tags: bash, hosts

I have a bash script `runmydocker.sh` that should grab the DNS string sent by the developer, when running he `runmydocker.sh` and create a new DNS inside the `/etc/hosts` dynamically and point to the docker server.

This is the flow:

- grab the DNS sent by the user and store it into a MYDNS variable
- copy the content of the current hosts
- insert 127.0.0.1 $MYDNS
- call docker run ....

So the user should do something like that:

```
./runmydocker.sh mysite.com
```

And when it write the URL mysite.com it should be using the docker server.

So my question here is how to insert this new DNS into `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: What is *a* DNS? DNS is the Domain Name System; there is only one of it for the entire Internet. Do you mean a fully qualified domain name (FQDN)?

Comment: Thing is you need root permission (sudo) to write to the file `/etc/hosts`. A simple example of the action would be like: `sudo echo x.x.x.x newsite.com >> /etc/hosts`. Of course you could embed such a line in your script and start your script from `crontab` as root, but whether that is the safest solution....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your script runs as root, you could do:

```
sed -i '/^127\.0\.0\.1\s/s/$/ '"$1"'/' /etc/hosts
```

`$1` is the first argument to the script (`mysite.com` for the example in the question). This command looks up the line containing `127.0.0.1` in the `hosts` file and appends the new domain to it.

You shouldn't add multiple lines with `127.0.0.1`, it could [potentially cause problems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102663/260978).

A better way is what the Ubuntu installer does - add a new address in the loopback range (`127.0.1.1`, for example). That's going to be trickier, since you'll need to find out the last loopback address added and increment it. I'll add a method for that if I find something simple enough.